# Woocommerce remove link in description product with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, woocommerce

Following a prestashop site transfer to woocommerce, I would like to remove all the old links added in the product description tab in order to avoid 404 errors. The description.php file contains :

```
the_content();
```

I would like to remove all the links present in `the_content()`, but keep the text.

I've tried `preg_replace` like this :

```php
$content = the_content();
echo preg_replace("/<a\s+href=['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^\>]*>[^<]+<\/a>/i",'$1', $content);
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Does this do what you want? I move the parentheses in the regex.

```php
$string =  "Remove the link (<a href='http://example.com'>Link Text 1</a>) here";
$string .= "\n";
$string .= 'Remove another (<a href="http://example.com">Link Text 2</a>) link';
$pattern = "/<a\s+href=['\"][^'\"]+['\"][^\>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>/i";
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $string);
```

Result

```
Remove the link (Link Text 1) here
Remove another (Link Text 2) link
```